# Google Drive API v3 files.list not returning all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I trying to get all search results, but getting only 2 files even if don't include any search requests (just trying to fetch a list of files).

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const keys = require('./keys.json');

const client = new google.auth.JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
);

client.authorize(function(err, tokens){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log('Connected!');
        gsrun(client);}
});

async function gsrun(cl){
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth:cl});
    const resDrive = await drive.files.list({
        pageSize: 5,
        // q: "name contains 'test'",
        spaces: 'drive',
    });

    const files = resDrive.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
        console.log('Files find:');
        files.map((file) => {
            console.log(`${file.name}, id: ${file.id}, link to file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/${file.id}/view`);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No files found.');
    }
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Since we have no idea what files are actually there or what their status is, we cannot possibly know whether you are seeing correct results, or what you expected to see

Comment: I'm sorry, there are a lot of files in different formats.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out)
The issue was in the permission - I had to share all files with the service account to get access.